# Can't access to configuration files at session start on Gnome

Tags: linux, redhat, gnome

I have troubles accessing to my gnome session.

I work on a Linux machine with red hat & gnome, and when I want to open my session, I get the error :

> "An error occurred while loading or saving configuration information
>   for gnome-session.  Some of your configuration settings may not work
>   properly.
>
> Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that
>   you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit,  or you have stale NFS
>   locks due to a system crash.  See http://www.gnome.org/projects/gconf/
>   for information.  IOR file '/tmp/gconfd-lepolmartin/lock/ior' not
>   opened successfully, no gconfd located: Permission denied"

I have checked, there is no folder gconfd-lepolmartin in /tmp. For some reason the files that Gnome are searching for do not exist in my session, but they do for other users of the same network that connect on the same machine.

Any idea ?

SLP

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. Have you tried https://superuser.com?

Comment: You're right, I will do this